# Dynamic List <malloc.h> free triggered a breakpoint - C Programming

Tags: c, dynamic, linked-list, breadth-first-search

Could someone help me with this one. I'm making BFS algorithm in C programming language, with help of dynamic lists.

This is my code.

```
// ConsoleApplication3.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <malloc.h>

#define n 6

typedef struct field
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int dist;
    struct field *next;
}Field;

// Get row and column number of 4 neighbours
int rows[] = { -1, 0, 0, 1 };
int cols[] = { 0, -1, 1, 0 };

Field *addToEnd(Field *lst, Field field)
{
    Field *newField = (Field*)malloc(sizeof Field);
    newField = &field;
    newField->next = NULL;

    if (!lst)
        return newField;
    else
    {
        Field *current;
        for (current = lst; current->next; current = current->next);
        current->next = newField;
        return lst;
    }
}

// Check if field is/isn't out of range
bool isValid(int row, int col)
{
    return (row >= 0) && (row < n) && (col >= 0) && (col < n);
}

int BFS(int mat[][n], Field source, Field destination)
{
    bool visited[n][n];
    memset(visited, false, sizeof visited);

    // Mark the source field as visited
    visited[source.x][source.y] = true;

    // Create dynamic list
    Field *lst = NULL;
    source.dist = 0;

    // Adding the source field to the list
    lst = addToEnd(lst, source);

    while (lst)
    {
        // Getting first element in the list
        Field current = *lst;

        // If destination is reached then end function
        if (current.x == destination.x && current.y == destination.y)
            return current.dist;

        // Delete first element of the list
        Field *toDelete;
        toDelete = lst;
        lst = lst->next;
        free(toDelete);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int row = current.x + rows[i];
            int col = current.y + cols[i];

            // If adjacent field is valid, has path and isn't visited add it to the list
            if (isValid(row, col) && mat[row][col] == 0 && !visited[row][col])
            {
                visited[row][col] = true;
                Field adjField = { row, col, current.dist + 1 };
                lst = addToEnd(lst, adjField);
            }
        }
    }

    // Return -1 if destination can't be reached
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int mat[n][n] = 
    {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 }
    };

    Field start = { 1, 0 }, end = { 5, 5 };

    int number = BFS(mat, start, end);

    if (number != -1)
        printf("%d\n", number);
    else
        printf("Destination can't be reached\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Everything except part of code which need to delete first element of list is working. The problem is with free function.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpK1j.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXp8d.png

Does anyone have an idea what could be possible wrong with this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to "Press Retry to debug the application"? Where in your code does the crash happen? What are the values of the involved variables?

Comment: By the way, `newField = &field` is wrong and a probable cause of the crash. Do you mean `*newField = field`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes thank you very much. I didn't looked at that one good. Thank you again.